# How to set jQuery resizable widget to resize around the center

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-ui

[jQuery resizable widget](https://api.jqueryui.com/resizable/) uses top-left coordinates as it's resizing center. But I want my element to rezise around it's center when resized using mouse.

It'd be nice if jQuery provided an option like this:

```
$( ".selector" ).resizable({ origin: 'center' });
```

But unfortunately this is [still an open issue](http://bugs.jqueryui.com/ticket/7878) for more than two years now.

Is it possible to achieve the above functionality using current jQuery API?

Comment: Would it be an option for you to consider using CSS3 transforms? If so , you can scale the div using CSS3 and set the transform-origin as center.

Comment: That's a nice alternative that I guess would be best when I am resizing the element using a drag-bar?

I want to resize the element using mouse pointer with resize controls on bottom-right corner.

Comment: You could insert a small div in the bottom right of your .selector div which responds on click/drag and updates the scale attribute accordingly. In theory at least!

Comment: sounds like a deal. lemme try that :)

Answer (score 0):

I hope this will help you out :

consider this **HTML**

```
<div class="demo">
            <div id="temp_resize" style="display: none;width: 350px;"></div>
            <div id="resizable" class="ui-widget-content">
                There are 2 method in css where you can make a div invisible. Its important to 
know how to hide a div or any given container dynamically, to improve the user interactions in 
modern web sites.

  blah blah blah

            </div>
```

the **CSS**

```
#resizable { 
            text-align:center;
            width: 350px; 
            height: 150px; 
            padding: 5px;
            overflow: hidden 
        }
        #resize_msg { 
            background-color: #3084DD; 
            color: #fff;
            width: 350px;
            padding: 5px;
            font-size: 14px;
            font-weight: bold;
        }
```

then the **jQuery** will be :

```
$(function() {


            $("#temp_resize").html($( "#resizable" ).html());
            var actual_height = $("#temp_resize").height() + 30;

            $( "#resizable" ).resizable({
                minWidth:350,maxWidth: 350,maxHeight:actual_height
            });

            $("#resizable").resize(function() {
                if($('#resizable').height() > (actual_height - 30)){
                    $("#resize_msg").html("No More Content");
                }else{
                    $("#resize_msg").html("Resize For More Content");
                }
            });

        });
```